# Dataflow worker lost contact with service

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Google Cloud Dataflow job is failing about an hour in with this message:

> 2022-03-08 12:59:23.337 PSTWorkflow failed. Causes:
> S08:group_by_airport/Read+group_by_airport/GroupByWindow+events_and_stats+events_to_features+into_global+shuffle/AddRandomKeys+shuffle/ReshufflePerKey/Map(reify_timestamps)+shuffle/ReshufflePerKey/GroupByKey/Reify+shuffle/ReshufflePerKey/GroupByKey/Write
> failed., The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look
> in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures.
> For more information, see
> https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work
> item was attempted on these workers:
> ch11traindata-03081130-cvo9-harness-xnps Root cause: The worker lost
> contact with the service., ch11traindata-03081130-cvo9-harness-qp67
> Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.,
> ch11traindata-03081130-cvo9-harness-lrq9 Root cause: The worker lost
> contact with the service., ch11traindata-03081130-cvo9-harness-5mwf
> Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.

Why would the worker lose contact with the service?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the worker crashed. Looking at the error message, it appears that it is happening in a GroupBy. Perhaps the worker is running out of memory or local swap space?

Try increasing the worker memory and disk size:

```
'--worker_machine_type=m1-ultramem-40', '--disk_size_gb=500'
```

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. I've requested quota for m1 machines, meanwhile I've rerun my job with the highest amount of memory available, n1-highmem-96, and it's still failing. According to Dataflow, max worker memory capacity is 10x the max worker memory usage. I'd love to see more guidance on how to measure and debug memory utilization in Dataflow/Beam.